# Opening a data file, appending lines and splitting data

Tags: java

I'm starting a project. I need to open a file and store all of the data into a single array.

I've tried using an array list but it is currently splitting each line with a ',' and storing multiple points into a single index whereas I need one point per index.
I've tried changing the ArrayList string to digit but it doesn't work.

Here is a part of the data file

```
150 4  
5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2
4.9 3 1.4 0.2
4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2
4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2
```

Here is my current code

```
    public static void main(String a[]){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String filename = "";
        String strLine = "";
        double arr[]; 

        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
        System.out.println(filename);

        String fn = myObj.nextLine();

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./phase1/" + fn));
              while (strLine != null)
               {
                strLine = br.readLine();
                sb.append(strLine);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                if (strLine==null)
                   break;
                list.add(strLine);
            }
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));

             br.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to read the file.");
        }



        // Removing the first line with the number of elements and dimensions 
      //  list.remove(0); 

        // Checking the the element was removed 
     //   System.out.println(list.get(0));

        // Printing elements one by one 
       for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) 
            System.out.print(list.get(i)+" "); 

      //    System.out.println("\n");
      //  System.out.print(list.get(0));



     }
```

My current output 
[150 4  , 5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2, 4.9 3 1.4 0.2, 4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2, 4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2, 5 3.6 1.4 0.2,]

Index(0) = 150 4

Expected output
Index(0) = 150
Index(1) = 4

Comment: Not related to your question but nonetheless good to know - assuming you are unaware of it. The code you posted includes `System.lineSeparator()`. This method was introduced in Java 1.7  Also introduced in Java 1.7 was [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to create an array of numbers from the content of the file. The sample numbers you provided are floating point numbers. Here is java code that reads the sample file you provided, line by line, splitting each line into individual numbers and converting the string into a `Float`. Each `Float` is added to an `ArrayList` and finally that `ArrayList` is converted to an array of `Float`.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NumArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java NumArray <file>");
        }
        else {
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]))) {
                ArrayList<Float> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
                String line = br.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                    for (String part : parts) {
                        numbers.add(Float.valueOf(part)); // throws java.lang.NumberFormatException
                    }
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
                Float[] numArray = new Float[numbers.size()];
                numbers.toArray(numArray);
                for (Float number : numbers) {
                    System.out.print(number);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            catch (IOException xIo) {
                xIo.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output...

> 150.0 4.0 5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2 4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2

Note the comment in my code: `throws java.lang.NumberFormatException`
If the file contains characters that cannot be converted to a `Float`, the program will crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to separate each number:

```
String numbers[] = strLine.split(" ");
```

Every element will be a single number in your case. Do that for every line and you are done :)

You can find the String.split documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Comment: I've tired that and now i'm getting getting the error. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at phase1.Main.main(Main.java:32)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 11 or higher, then you can use `Files#readString` and Java 8 or higher for streams to simplify the code:

```
// write the content to string
String content = Files.readString(path, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII); 
// split by non alphanumeric character and create stream
double[] array = Stream.of(content.split("\\W+"))
                       .mapToDouble(Double::valueOf) // map to double
                       .toArray(); // write as array
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); // print the array
```

Comment: I'm unable to use String content. I tried to use buffer reader with the double array inside of the while statement. However, I'm getting an error.

Comment: That's because you are using a older java version, check it with `java --version`. Just read the file to string using https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/09/how-to-read-file-into-string-in-java-7.html approach.